Let $f(a,n) = a^n$. If $f(a,n-1) = f(a,n)-1$, what is $a+n$?
Let $f(a,n) = a^n$. If $f(a,n-1) = f(a,n)-1$, what is $a+n$?
This question has been taken from a practice Online Olympiad test from Bangladesh. I believe this question is assuming that $a,n \in \Bbb R$. However, it wasn't specified.
My working so far:
$a^{n-1} = a^n-1$
$\Rightarrow a^{n-1} - a^n = -1$
$\Rightarrow a^n-a^{n-1} = 1$
$\Rightarrow a^n × (1-(\frac{1}{a})) = 1$
And I got stuck at this step. So I tried out the following but it was in vain:
Knowing $1 = -1 × -1$, Let $(1-(\frac 1a)) = -1$
$\Rightarrow 1-(\frac 1a) = -1$
$\Rightarrow -(\frac 1a) = -2$
$\Rightarrow \frac 1a = 2$
$\Rightarrow a = \frac 12$
As before, let $a^n = -1$
$\Rightarrow (\frac 12)^n = -1$
No real values of $n$ yields $-1$
I don't understand what to do next. I suppose I need to try out different values of $a$ and $n$, but I'm not sure. Any help would be nice!
P.S: I'm sorry if the answer was obvious, this question has me stumped for a while now.

Step 1: Set $n=1$, solve for $a=2$.  Set $n=2$, solve for $a=\phi$.  Conclude that $a+n$ isn't determined by the equation.  Step 2: Look for whether there's a typo or some detail you missed.  If not, find a better source.

@BrianMoehring No typos as I just checked, and I can't find the question from any other source. I think $a = 2$ and $n = 1$ being the solutions is what the question intended, because the answer space only allowed for numerical values.

It seems to me like you were supposed to assume $a$ and $n\ge1$ are integers so you get $a^{n-1}(a-1)=1$ and because $a$ is an integer the only solution is for $(a,n) = (2,1)$.
This is the only solution because if $n\ge1$ both $a^{n-1}$ and $(a-1)$ are integers and hence must both be $1$ or both be $-1$. In the first case you get $a=2$ and $n=1$ and the second case you get $a=0$ which gives no solution that satisfies $a^n = a^{n-1} +1$.

I see that you've taken $a^{n-1}$ as common instead of $a^n$ from the expressions, but $a^n$ should work the same, no?

Not really, if you take $a^n$ out of both terms then you are left with a fraction and you can’t use the fact that the only integers factors of $1$ are $\pm 1$.

Oh right, that makes sense! Thanks!
